# Breeze: 'A nonnullable DataProperty cannot have a null defaultValue. Name: undefined'

Tags: breeze, geography

the error depends on a field of type geography in my SQL Server db. This field is not nullable and has a default property.
I tried to add JsonIgnore attribute to this field, but it is still present in metadata and I have this error:
Metadata import failed for breeze/BreezeMyPlace/Metadata; Unable to process returned metadata:A nonnullable DataProperty cannot have a null defaultValue. Name: undefined.
I'm using nuget packages "Breeze for ASP.NET Web API projects v. 1.3.3", Entity Framework 5.0, JSon.NET 5.0.5, etc.
How can I prevent serialization of this field?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[JsonIgnore]` attribute tells the JSON formatter to ignore the property during serialization but it is still part of the EF model and it still appears in the metadata generated from the `DbContext`. Serialization and Metadata are distinct concerns.

You can hide it from metadata by adding the EDM `[NotMapped]` attribute to the property in your model.

If you don't want to touch your model, you can tell EF to ignore it via Fluent Configuration in your `DbContext`, e.g,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Ignore(t => t.CustomerID_OLD);
```

If you need that property to be accessible in server logic but hidden from Breeze metadata, you can create a dedicated `MetadataDbContext` that inherits from your working `DbContext` and put the "ignore" code in there. See the `NorthwindMetadataContext` in DocCode for an example.

**Reminder**: In general, you can only hide nullable properties from EF. This will work in your case because the non-nullable property has a default value defined in the database schema. Otherwise, the database would reject inserts.

Comment: Thank you, I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275184/how-can-i-tell-breeze-to-completely-ignore-a-property-from-a-code-first-generate too so NorthwindMetadataContext is the right example for me. Now I have troubles because I'm using Database first approach and onmodelcreating is not called...